# Is it possible to add borders to an excel range automatically by using datanitro?

Tags: datanitro

Is it possible to add borders to an excel range automatically by using datanitro? 
i.e. something like:

```
>>> CellRange("A1:A5").upper_border= True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly, but there are two workarounds:

- Write a VBA function to do it and call that from DataNitro: https://datanitro.com/docs/vba.html#calling-vba-from-datanitro
- Copy the formatting from a cell that has it already: https://datanitro.com/docs/cellrange.html?highlight=format#copy_format_from

Comment: Brilliant - that's good enough. Solution is probably to define a few cells in the worksheet with the desired format, then use those as the template for other cells. Thanks!